# Visual Studios, Find window too big

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I open the Find in Files dialog (by pressing ctrl+shift+f) is is *way too big*.

It looks like its exactly as wide or slightly wider then the screen width. But it pops up in the middle of my screen so usually when I need to switch the find path (from a fix location to entire solution) I can't click the arrow. Its really annoying

How do I fix that? I tried reducing the width and closing VS but after opening I still get the same width problem

Comment: Have you tried docking the window to one side? Alternatively, you could just reset the VS IDE settings.

Comment: @Randolph: Docking doesnt help. The window is either too large or short enough that i cant click find (or sometimes check off settings). I need it floating.

Answer (score 0):

Get the PPT VS extension.  It features a Chrome Browser style find box...
Plus the extension adds a number of improvements like Ctrl Click "Goto Definition" and a combined Solution explorer/Class View Toolbox called Solution Navigator.

[image: Look]

edit:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef